# How to write a correct querySelector

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, selector

My full js

```
navHighlighter() {

const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section[id]");
let scrollY = window.pageYOffset;

sections.forEach(current => {
  const sectionHeight = current.clientHeight;

  const sectionTop = (current.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset) - 50;
  var sectionId = current.getAttribute("id");

  var indicator = document.querySelector(".indexing a[(click)=jump(" + sectionId + ")] ");

  if (scrollY > sectionTop && scrollY <= sectionTop + sectionHeight) {
    indicator?.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    indicator?.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

}

This is the html I want to write in queryselector

```
<div class="indexing">   
   <a (click)="jump('labeled')">Labeled</a>
   <a (click)="jump('grey')">Labeled</a>
</div>
```

And below is the wrong selector i wrote :

```
var indicator = document.querySelector(".indexing a[(click)=jump(" + sectionId + ")] ");
```

Labeled is the sectionId

Comment: Id argue that working with query selector or elementbyx is an anitpattern in framworks such as angular.

Comment: @mplungjan there I wrote it's parent.

Comment: @mplungjan i'm using foreach loop, and current method. Using specific Id is messy work

Comment: Sound like a dupe of [one of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+highlight+navigation+when+scroll+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the reference brother, but in there it is only working because the site only contain one navigation list. In my case, my vertical navigation is changing depending on my router url.

Comment: it will never work such as described in the question, because there will be no (click) attribute on the runtime. only during the compilation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using escape characters in order to select an attribute name with parentheses.

```
document.querySelector(".indexing a[\\(click\\)=\"jump('" + sectionId + "')\"]");
```

Comment: Thank you , this is correct. However it returns null since the attribute is does not exist. But i found a workaround. Many thanks